# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error with only numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

I know what the error is, but why would it display this error if there are no other characters? I know this question has been asked but I can't find a reason for it.

error line code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tudor/Documents/python/custom cypher/cypher.py", line 179, in 
<module>
array0, array1, array2 = (int(crypt_array0) // array0_key), 
(int(crypt_array1) // array1_key), (int(crypt_array2) // array2_key)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

full code:

```
import random
import itertools
print ('''
         READ THIS BEFORE USE

    This encryption can ONLY use ASCII
    this contains most/all of the 
    keys on your keyboard, this
    includes capital letters

    The key supports around 100000 digits.

    The hard encoding adds three more
    layers of security. You will have to
    copy your new key.

    ''')

hard_encoding_1 = {
'0': '8',
'1': '4',
'2': '3',
'3': '7',
'4': '1',
'5': '9',
'6': '5',
'7': '6',
'8': '2',
'9': '0',
}

hard_encoding_2 = {
'0': '5',
'1': '9',
'2': '0',
'3': '1',
'4': '4',
'5': '3',
'6': '7',
'7': '2',
'8': '6',
'9': '8',
}

hard_encoding_3 = {
'0': '2',
'1': '5',
'2': '7',
'3': '4',
'4': '9',
'5': '8',
'6': '1',
'7': '0',
'8': '3',
'9': '6',
}

hard_encoding_4 = {
'0': '1',
'1': '3',
'2': '5',
'3': '8',
'4': '0',
'5': '7',
'6': '6',
'7': '2',
'8': '9',
'9': '4',
}


def randint_generator(n):
    key_generate = ''
    for b in range(n):
        b = random.randint(0, 9)
        key_generate = key_generate + str(b)
    return 'copy this key: ' + key_generate


def setnumber(x, y, str_or_int):
    n = len(str(x))
    z = str(x)
    while n != y:
        z = '0' + z
        n = len(z)
    if str_or_int == str:
        return str(z)
    if str_or_int == int:
        return int(z)


while True:
    What_operation = int(input('''
        Do you want to:
        soft:
            decrypt(0)
            encrypt(1)
        hard:
            decrypt(3)
            encrypt(4)
        generate a key:
            100-digit(5)
            500-digit(6)
            1,000-digit(7)
            10,000-digit(8)
            1,000,000-digit(9)
            '''))


if What_operation == 1:
    text = input('What is your text you want to convert? ')
    New_text = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(), 'big'))
    key = int(input('What is your key you want to use?'))
    cyphered_text = int(New_text[2:]) * key
    print ('copy this text: ', cyphered_text)

if What_operation == 0:
    numbers = input('What is your string you want to convert? ')
    key = int(input('What is your key? '))
    New_text = '0b' + str(int(numbers) // key)
    encoded = int(New_text,2)
    decoded = encoded.to_bytes((encoded.bit_length() + 7) // 8,                 
'big').decode()
    print ('Here is your message: ' + decoded)

if What_operation == 4:
    text = input('What is your text you want to convert? ')
    New_text = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(), 'big'))
    key = int(input('What is your key you want to use?'))
    key_2 = random.randint(1,4)
    cyphered_text = New_text[2:]
    hard_cyphered_text = ''
    cyphered_text = int(cyphered_text) * key
    for i in str(cyphered_text):
        if key_2 == 1:
            hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_1[i]
        if key_2 == 2:
            hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_2[i]
        if key_2 == 3:
            hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_3[i]
        if key_2 == 4:
            hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_4[i]
    x_cyphered_text = str(hard_cyphered_text)
    array0 = ''
    array1 = ''
    array2 = ''
    count = 0
    for i in x_cyphered_text:
        if count % 3 == 0:
            array0 += i
        count += 1
    count = 0
    for i in x_cyphered_text:
        if count % 3 == 1:
            array1 += i
        count += 1
    count = 0
    for i in x_cyphered_text:
        if count % 3 == 2:
            array2 += i
        count += 1
    array0_key, array1_key, array2_key = random.randint(1, 99999999), 
    random.randint(1, 99999999), random.randint(1, 99999999)
    final_array0, final_array1, final_array2 = int(array0) * array0_key,                 
    int(array1) * array1_key, int(array2) * array2_key
    len_array0, len_array1, len_array2 = str(len(str(final_array0))), 
    str(len(str(final_array1))), str(len(str(final_array2)))
    full_key = str(key) + str(key_2) + setnumber(len_array0, 6, str) + 
    setnumber(len_array1, 6, str) + setnumber(len_array2, 6, str) + 
    setnumber(array0_key, 8, str) + setnumber(array1_key, 8, str) + 
    setnumber(array2_key, 8, str)
    complete_cyphered_text = str(final_array0) + str(final_array1) + 
    str(final_array2)
    print('copy this text: ', complete_cyphered_text)
    print('Copy your key: ', full_key)

if What_operation == 3:
    numbers = input('What is your string you want to convert? ')
    key = input('What is your given key? ')
    key_2 = int(key[-43:-42])
    array2_key, array1_key, array0_key = int(key[-8:]), int(key[-16:-8]),     
    int(key[-24:-16])
    len_array2, len_array1, len_array0 = int(key[-30:-24]), 
    int(key[-36:-30]), int(key[-42:-36])
    n0, n1, n2 = len_array0, len_array1, len_array2
    crypt_array0, crypt_array1, crypt_array2 = numbers[:n0], numbers[n0:n1], 
    numbers[n0 + n1:]
    array0, array1, array2 = (int(crypt_array0) // array0_key), 
    (int(crypt_array1) // array1_key), (int(crypt_array2) // array2_key) ###
    numbers_noncrypt = ''.join(''.join(x) for x in 
    itertools.zip_longest(str(array0), str(array1), str(array2), 
    fillvalue=''))
    key = int(str(key)[:-43])
    encoded_text = ''
    decoding = {}
    if key_2 == 1:
        decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_1.items()}
    if key_2 == 2:
        decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_2.items()}
    if key_2 == 3:
        decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_3.items()}
    if key_2 == 4:
        decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_4.items()}
    for i in str(numbers_noncrypt):
        encoded_text = encoded_text + decoding[i]
    encoded_text = '0b' + str(int(encoded_text) // key)
    encoded = int(encoded_text, 2)
    decoded = encoded.to_bytes((encoded.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 
    'big').decode()
    print ('Here is your message: ' + decoded)

if What_operation == 5:
    print(randint_generator(100))
if What_operation == 6:
    print(randint_generator(500))
if What_operation == 7:
    print(randint_generator(1000))
if What_operation == 8:
    print(randint_generator(10000))
if What_operation == 9:
    print(randint_generator(1000000))
```

By the way, the `//` is not a comment, it is division in python to output in integers and not float, also the code looks crowded as there is a limit on how long the lines have to be on this website. I will put `###` to the error line refers to.

I tried debugging it and approaching it in a different way but I can't find a reason why it would do this.

Comment: This is too much code. Try to condense this down into a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get your debugging going, you're trying to convert an empty string into an integer. To see where this is going wrong, you might want to split up:

```
array0, array1, array2 = (int(crypt_array0) // array0_key), 
(int(crypt_array1) // array1_key), (int(crypt_array2) // array2_key) ###
```

to:

```
array0 = (int(crypt_array0) // array0_key)
array1 = (int(crypt_array1) // array1_key)
array2 = (int(crypt_array2) // array2_key)
```

This way it's easier to follow what exactly is going wrong. Also, please only post the appropriate code in the future.

Comment: I will remember, I tried printing out the key and the crypted array and it all turned out fine, the full key is **1231000022000022000021455682723953581397310365** and the full crypted message **19081440225059951078882921424486495819287041948501439112006936475**. It displayed **45568272** as array0_key which is correct and **1908144022505995107888** as crypt_array0, which is also correct I can't seem to find a solution for this.